# SQL for determining true/false based on two table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table that contains a row for each field on a form that is submitted.

```
CREATE TABLE `FormResponses` (
  `responseID` char(35) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `formID` char(35) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `formField` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `formValue` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  
)
```

If a submitted form had 2 fields (user_id, and audio_file_id), there would be two rows, both having the same responseID and formId.

Now, I need to query the table to determine if a user_id has submitted the form for a particular audio_file_id (to prevent duplicate submissions for an audio file, while allowing submissions for other audio files using the same form).

The pseudoquery might look like:

```
SELECT responseId
FROM FormResponses
WHERE formId = FORM_ID_VALUE AND EXISTS 


( SELECT responseID 
  FROM FormResponses 
  WHERE formField = "user_id" AND formValue = USER_ID_VALUE

AND

 SELECT responseID
 FROM FormResponses
 WHERE formField = "audio_file_id" AND formValue = AUDIO_FILE_ID_VALUE AND responseID = RESPONSE_ID_OF_USER_ID_QUERY_ABOVE

)
```

Basically, the plain English query would be "give me the response ID of the two rows where the formId = 123, and one of those two rows represents a user_id of 456 and the other of those two rows represents an audio_file_id of 789."

Of note:  If a user submits the same form for two different audio files, the responseID for those two submits will be different, but the formID will be the same.

I hope I am asking this clearly enough... hopefully it's just harder to explain than to do!

Comment: please post some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have to combine data from two rows in the same table you do an auto join, i.e. you query the table twice and call them for instance a and b. Then you get the one row from table a and the other from table b. If all the criteria are met, you will get a resulting row:

```
SELECT a.responseId
FROM FormResponses a 
JOIN FormResponses b
ON a.formId = b.formId
AND a.responseId = b.responseId
WHERE a.formId = FORM_ID_VALUE
AND a.formField = 'user_id'
AND a.formValue = USER_ID_VALUE
AND b.formField = 'audio_file_id'
AND b.formValue = AUDIO_FILE_ID_VALUE
```

Comment: should the ON be based on the responseId, since that's what ties the two rows together? As it is right now, the "b" table will return all form responses having that audio file ID, but won't take the user into account, won't it?

Comment: You're right of course. Just testing your understanding :-) Edited accordingly.

Comment: Excellent. Not even sure the join on a.formId = b.formId is required, and mine is working well without it. Here's my final solution, anyway, but your answer is clearly The One. Also, thanks for testing my understanding, I needed that! lol

Comment: my final solution (uses actual table name now that the issue is resolved):

SELECT 
  a.responseId

 FROM 
  tformresponsequestions a 
   JOIN 
  tformresponsequestions b ON
   a.responseId = b.responseId

 WHERE
  ( 
   a.formId = '#$.content('callEvaluationFormId')#'
    AND 
   a.formField = 'user_id'
    AND 
   a.formValue = '#$.currentUser().getUserId()#'
  )

   AND
  ( 
   b.formId = '#$.content('callEvaluationFormId')#'
    AND 
   b.formField = 'audio_file_id'
    AND
   b.formValue = '#$.content('audio_file')#'
  )

Comment: Well, you did say `of the two rows where the formId = 123`. Instead of `b.formId = '#$.content('callEvaluationFormId')#'` you could say `b.formId = a.formId`. If you put that in the join criteria, your query might be faster (not sure if mySql optimizes that anyway).

Comment: I'll check it out and see if there's a way to determine which is faster (though this is such a small pool of users it absolutely won't matter). Just for the sake of science or whatever.

itsLex, I owe you a beer.  THANK YOU very much.